# What is the use of response.addHeader when we have response.setContentType in java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, response

May i know the use of response.addHeader when we already have response.setContentType in java...
I m unable find proper solution.

```
<% response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Report.xls"); %>

<% response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); %>
```

Here the above second statement is enough to get response as excel format. 
which scenario i need to use response.addHeader ?

please ...

Answer (score 6):

This particular header :

```
"Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Report.xls"
```

tells the browser to download the file as an attachment with default name `Report.xls`.

Also check the [HTTP/1.1 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-170)

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a
> means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user
> requests that the content is saved to a file.

> An example is

```
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

> The receiving user agent SHOULD NOT respect any directory path
> information present in the filename-parm parameter, which is the only
> parameter believed to apply to HTTP implementations at this time. The
> filename SHOULD be treated as a terminal component only.

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet-
> stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent
> should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response
> as...' dialog.

**Remember though** , HTTP/1.1 defines the *Content-Disposition* response header field, but points out that it is not part of the HTTP/1.1 Standard.

---

IMHO , don't use JSP to do the downloading stuff , use a Servlet instead !

Answer (score 0):

I don't write in Java, but I know there are many sharing the same feature.

And IMO it's just a shortcut.

BTW, there are so many headers... Not just Content-Type or something like that.